# How activate or deactivate a button from a list of buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a list of buttons inside a div that emulates a project preview in a dashboard. I want to let the user select the project so it can be opened or erased.

So I need a function (that for sure exists but I don't know it) to identify the list of buttons inside the div, and when the user clicks on one button, activate it and simultaneously deactivate the other buttons

I'm identifying the buttons like:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#buttonscontainer');
var matches = container.querySelectorAll('div.divscontainer > button');
//identify the buttons inside the div, maybe not necessary...
  for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    //activate the current button
    //deactivate other buttons (if ever been activated) 
  }
```

May be with an `addEventListener` inside the div, but I don't know where to begin.

**I don't want an exact answer of course**, just a tip to know with which functions can I start exploring.

Hope it's clear enough,

Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: This is not a question to complete the code, this is a question of how to make a list of buttons selectable between them. The fact I've put the border color and stuff is to clarify the aim of the code, not to ask for the exact code... Sorry if it wasn't clear enough, I'll try to remake the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want:

```html
<div id="buttonscontainer">
  <button class="btn" id="btn1">action 1</button>
  <button class="btn" id="btn2">action 2</button>
  <button class="btn" id="btn3">action 3</button>
  <button class="btn" id="btn4">action 4</button>
</div>

<style>
  .btn {
    animation: btn 1s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes btn {
    50% {
      outline: 3px solid blue;
    }
  }

  .btn--selected {
    outline: 3px solid yellow !important;
  }
</style>

<script>
  const buttonscontainer = document.getElementById('buttonscontainer')
  buttonscontainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const target = event.target
    if (target.className !== 'btn') return

    Array.from(buttonscontainer.children).forEach(child => child.classList.remove('btn--selected'))
    target.classList.add('btn--selected')
  })

</script>
```

We give an animation to the buttons so that the user knows that they are selectable, in this case we put a blue outline. `infinite` means that it always does the animation.
Also, we listen with an event when there's a click on any button in order to put it a class with a yellow outline in it.

If anyone has any questions about this code, let me know and I'll be happy to explain it.

Comment: You might've missed the `event` as parameter of the callback. Also, some might think that the return is returning the `Array.from` instead of being a safeguard, so it could be better to add a blank like, semicolons or invert the if.

Comment: This does the exact thing I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your time spent!!